# MSIE using smartphone CSS for animation

Tags: css, animation

I have a CSS animation that runs when a page is loaded. It scales an image from small to large and fades in using opacity.

It works on all browsers except....yep....MSIE. I'm using MSIE on Windows 8.

MSIE seems to be using the smartphone CSS in all cases, regardless of viewport size.

If I remove the animation classes from the smartphone CSS, it uses the right CSS. In Inspector, it claims it's using the correct stylesheet.

Any ideas why this would happen?

This problem started happening after I put the animation classes in the smartphone and tablet CSS files. Is there some reason MSIE doesn't support responsive CSS animations or something? If I remove the animation classes from the smartphone CSS file, MSIE works as expected.

Thank you in advance!

Code (The curly braces are Shopify Liquid tags)

HTML - External CSS Links

```
    {{ 'core.scss' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width:680px) and (max-width:980px) and (orientation:portrait)" href="{{ 'tabletportrait.css' | asset_url }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:679px)" href="{{ 'smartphone.css' | asset_url }}" />
```

HTML - DIV intended to be animated

```
    <div id="imgWatermark" class="imgWatermark">
      <img src="{{ 'imgLogo.png' | asset_url }}" alt="Logo" id="mainLogoImg" class="mainLogoImg">
      <img src="{{ 'bgGradient_lg.png' | asset_url }}" id="mainLogoImgBg" class="mainLogoImgBg">
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
  imgWatermarkEl = document.getElementById('imgWatermark');
  mainLogoImgEl = document.getElementById('mainLogoImg');
  mainLogoImgBgEl = document.getElementById('mainLogoImgBg');

  // Display the imgWatermark DIV container
  imgWatermarkEl.style.display = 'block';

  // Start the mainLogoImg animation
  mainLogoImgEl.style.animation = 'mainLogoImg_ani 1s forwards';
  mainLogoImgEl.style.webkitAnimation = 'mainLogoImg_ani 1s forwards';

  // Start the mainLogoImgBg animation
  mainLogoImgBgEl.style.animation = 'mainLogoImgBg_ani 1s forwards';
  mainLogoImgBgEl.style.webkitAnimation = 'mainLogoImgBg_ani 1s forwards';

  // Initiate animation event listeners
  mainLogoImgEl.addEventListener('animationend', showItems);
  mainLogoImgEl.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', showItems);
```

CSS - Core

```
.imgWatermark {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 25;
}

.mainLogoImg {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;  
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 501px;
    width: 586px;   
    margin: auto auto;  
    z-index: 25;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;

    // The properties below are being set in Javascript after the main site navigation loads
    // animation: mainLogoImg_ani 1s forwards;
    // -webkit-animation: mainLogoImg_ani 1s forwards;
}

.mainLogoImgBg {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto auto;
    z-index: 20;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;

    // The properties below are being set in Javascript after the main site navigation loads
    // animation: mainLogoImgBg_ani 1s forwards;
    // -webkit-animation: mainLogoImgBg_ani 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes mainLogoImg_ani {
    0% {
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    80% {
        height: 501px;
        width: 586px;
        opacity: 1.0;
    }

    100% {
        height: 501px;
        width: 586px;
        opacity: 0.1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes mainLogoImg_ani {
    0% {
        height: 0;
        width: 0;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    80% {
        height: 501px;
        width: 586px;
        opacity: 1.0;
    }

    100% {
        height: 501px;
        width: 586px;
        opacity: 0.1;
    }
}
```

CSS - Smartphone

```
.mainLogoImg {  
}

.mainLogoImgBg {

}

@keyframes mainLogoImg_ani {
    0% {
        height: 0px;
        width: 0px;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    80% {
        height: 251px;
        width: 293px;
        opacity: 1.0;
    }

    100% {
        height: 251px;
        width: 293px;
        opacity: 0.1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes mainLogoImg_ani {
0% {
   height: 0px;
   width: 0px;
   opacity: 0;
}

80% {
    height: 251px;
    width: 293px;
    opacity: 1.0;
}

    100% {
        height: 251px;
        width: 293px;
        opacity: 0.1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: It's tough to do. I have CSS classes in three stylesheets - one for core, smartphone, and tablet. I'm setting the animation using Javascript. I just thought someone might have an idea why it'd be doing it. It works in all browsers except MSIE. All other classes in MSIE are working as expected. It's very odd.

Comment: But we have nearly no information at all. You only say it is having a problem on IE. And that's it.

Comment: I added relevant code snippets.

Comment: But what IE version and which OS are you using? IE9 doesn't support animations. IE10 requires the prefix `-ms-` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/hh673530.aspx).

Comment: MSIE 11 on Windows 8.